# ExoPlayer: What's the best way to handle lazy loading of a playlist?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I have a playlist with basic information about each media, I don't know anything about streaming data for the media (meaning it could be DASH, HLS, etc.) I would like to lazily create MediaSource for each media in the playlist. Meaning upon next/previous my app would create a MediaSource for the media. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi Cubxity! Welcome to stack overflow. Can you provide a bit more detail about what exactly you're trying to do, maybe a code example?

Comment: @JamesRiordan I'm trying to play a playlist in ExoPlayer. But I don't want all the MediaSource to be initialized at once because I would need to call the API for every of them.

Comment: can you provide a code example?

Comment: @Cubxity, Are you able to fix this, I am stuck with the same thing

Comment: @B.shruti I have not found a fix, so instead I need to prepare new media source manually when navigating to the next video

Answer (score 1):

From https://exoplayer.dev/playlists.html

> It’s possible to dynamically modify a playlist by adding, removing and
>   moving MediaSources within a ConcatenatingMediaSource. This can be
>   done both before and during playback by calling the corresponding
>   ConcatenatingMediaSource methods. The player automatically handles
>   modifications during playback in the correct way. For example if the
>   currently playing MediaSource is moved, playback is not interrupted
>   and its new successor will be played upon completion. If the currently
>   playing MediaSource is removed, the player will automatically move to
>   playing the first remaining successor, or transition to the ended
>   state if no such successor exists.

You can create your sources and then just add them to the playlist with the `addMediaSource` call (see reference [here](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/ConcatenatingMediaSource.html#addMediaSource-int-com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource-))

Without a code example of some kind or more detail, it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but I'd expect the solution to involve you lazily creating the sources and then adding them to the playlist when they're created.

Comment: Would it be possible at all to not initialize the media source until the user skips to it?

Comment: Yes, but it takes time to load, so you'd see the ended state for some time, or the next media item. You'd be better to preload a couple of items after the currently playing one.

Comment: What do apps like YouTube and Spotify do?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, this is something you could try researching yourself. I'd expect they're using something proprietary instead of exoplayer. I'd guess this is stateful, so the player doesn't have to spin up an HLS stream or similar for each item. This makes it much easier to change items quickly.

Comment: is there any way to get the playlist duration in exoplayer?

Comment: You should probably ask that as a new question. Comments aren't really meant for extra questions like this.